# Incomplete data displayed by table

Tags: php

The first query displays two values in the `Office` table:

```
peter
James
```

I would like to display data in the second query where the field `office_manager` contains the two values in the `Claims_Assigned` table.

```
$req="SELECT ContactName FROM  Office p inner join    
claims_follow_up.user o On p.ClientID=o.office Where o.username='".$u."'
and o.password='".$p."' "; 
$resc = mysqli_query($dbc, $req);

while($tab=mysqli_fetch_array($resc)) 
{
  $clname=$tab['ContactName'];

  echo $clname;
  $req7= "select * from Claims_assigned where  
          office_manager='".$clname."' "; 
  $resz = @mysqli_query($dbc, $req7);   
  <table>
    <th>Claim Status</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Insurance Carrier</th>
    </tr>
    while($final_result =mysqli_fetch_array($resz))
    {
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $final_result['Claim_Status'] ;?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $final_result['office'];?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $final_result['insurance_carrier'];?></td>
      </tr>
    }
}
</table>
```

The second query displays data for `peter` only. How do I display data for `james` as well, a value that is also found in the `Claims_assigned` table?

Comment: Firstly, you have a `</tr>` without an opener....

Comment: Secondly, you can run your querys like this without concatenating the string.... `$req7= "select * from Claims_assigned where  
office_manager=$clname"; `

Comment: i add the open <tr> and office_manager='$clname' it's still not working..

Comment: Some body can help me please ?

Comment: You should really be using http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php This is highly vulnerable to injection attacks, and is a form of using a db connection that makes it difficult to reason about what you're doing. Have you tried running these queries on your db in raw form (w/o php)? Have you tried to `echo` the length of the results you're getting back? How are you sure that the problem is here and not elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe there is no James or Peter in the second table?!

Comment: ok i got it i check..